# How to fix an error related to UTF-8/ASCII

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, utf-8

Ok, I've got an App built using Rails 4.2 and MongoDB (MongoId V4) for storage. The information (text) stored in some of the tables/collections is a mix of English and Danish. The App is not localized in any way/shape/form yet as it is an API only.

I have a Sidekiq worker that updates the documents in my database. The problem I'm having is that every time a document is updated in Sidekiq, I get the following error:

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 output in Sidekiq.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use enforce encoding to utf8 using string.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8) before you update that specific record

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work... Still got the sam error.

Comment: Theoretically that should work if you are applying it to the expected string. if you really want to fix it then you have to print/puts the encoding of that string that's giving that error, then you will be sure if that force_encoding is working on that string, string.encoding should give you the encoding then you know whats going on